# Is there a way to automate open source Screen readers (NVDA)? For accessibility Testing

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate an open source Screen readers like NVDA for windows, VO for MAC etc... for my accessibility Project can we automate the mentioned screen reader using selenium or any other automation tool using JAVA.

Comment: Are you asking for a complete code? or have you tried to do this and couldn't manage it? if so, please show us your work so we can know how to help.

Comment: I am not asking for a complete code i am Just asking is there a way to automate the screen readers like NVDA & VO, if there is a way to do it what are the tool we need to use for automating the Screen readers?

Comment: I hope you know selenium is for automated webbrowser tests (not for any desktop applications). Anyways what do you mean by "automate an open source Screen reader"? Could you give some examples of what you are looking for?

Comment: ya i am aware that selenium works only for web based applications Only. That's why i want to know any other tools for automating the Screen reader's with respect to the web application as well as desktop application using JAVA